# Append data to a .JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this .json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Ben\\'s First Blog Post",
        "content": "This is the content"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Ben\\'s Second Blog Post",
        "content": "This is the content"
    }
]
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$data[] = $_POST['data'];

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'a');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
fclose($fp);
```

The thing is, I'm not exactly sure how to achieve it. I'm going to call this code above every time a form is submitted, so I need the ID to increment and to also keep the valid JSON structure with `[` and `{`, is this possible?

Comment: I don't think JSON is an incremental format; you'll have to deserialise it, add your new record, and serialise it again.

Comment: I know it's not the answer to your question, but this reminds me of a time I tried to do the same thing with XML. The purpose was storing blog posts, and I thought it was going to be a cool way to avoid needing MySQL.

This, however, did not turn out to be the case. It's more reliable, better practice, and way less pain in the long run, to use a database rather than a file for this kind of data.

I apologize, I know it's super annoying when you ask a question and someone gives "don't do that" as an answer (which is why I'm posting this as a comment). It's just what I wish I'd been told sooner.

Comment: Append data to a .JSON file  [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290572/appending-to-json-file-in-javascript

Comment: how would the file being interpreted as data need to be formatted for this to work?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$data[] = $_POST['data'];

$inp = file_get_contents('results.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
array_push($tempArray, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('results.json', $jsonData);
```

Comment: Won't this take longer to do every time? Couldn't it get pretty ridiculous when you have a HUGE JSON file? I am dealing with a lot of data.

Comment: newbie php guy here... how do I amend the answer above to work if I am getting my "post data" using file_get_contents('php://input')?   So basically the first line doesn't work for me.  I am using file_get_contents('php://input') because I am calling fetch() in JS to make the http post.

Answer (score 34):

This has taken the above c example and moved it over to php. This will jump to the end of the file and add the new data in without reading all the file into memory.

```
// read the file if present
$handle = @fopen($filename, 'r+');

// create the file if needed
if ($handle === null)
{
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
}

if ($handle)
{
    // seek to the end
    fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);

    // are we at the end of is the file empty
    if (ftell($handle) > 0)
    {
        // move back a byte
        fseek($handle, -1, SEEK_END);

        // add the trailing comma
        fwrite($handle, ',', 1);

        // add the new json string
        fwrite($handle, json_encode($event) . ']');
    }
    else
    {
        // write the first event inside an array
        fwrite($handle, json_encode(array($event)));
    }

        // close the handle on the file
        fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Great Solution! Initially didn't work for me. Had to repalce $handle === null with $handle == null

Answer (score 17):

You're ruining your json data by blindly appending text to it. JSON is not a format that can be manipulated like this.

You'll have to load your json text, decode it, manipulate the resulting data structure, then re-encode/save it.

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('results.json');
$data = json_decode($json);
$data[] = $_POST['data'];
file_put_contents('results.json', json_encode($data));
```

Let's say you've got `[1,2,3]` stored in your file. Your code could turn that into `[1,2,3]4`, which is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add another array element to a JSON file as your example shows, open the file and seek to the end.  If the file already has data, seek backwards one byte to overwrite the `]` following the last entry, then write `,` plus the new data minus the initial `[` of the new data.  Otherwise, it's your first array element, so just write your array normally.

Sorry I don't know enough about PHP to post actual code, but I've done this in Obj-C and it's allowed me to avoid reading the whole file in first just to add onto the end:

```
NSArray *array = @[myDictionary];
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:0 error:nil];
FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r+");
if (NULL == fp)
    fp = fopen(fname, "w+");
if (fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    if (ftell(fp) > 0) {
        fseek(fp, -1L, SEEK_END);
        fwrite(",", 1, 1, fp);
        fwrite([data bytes] + 1, [data length] - 1, 1, fp);
    }
    else
        fwrite([data bytes], [data length], 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sample code I used to append additional JSON array to JSON file.

```
$additionalArray = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'title' => $title,
    'content' => $content
);

//open or read json data
$data_results = file_get_contents('results.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($data_results);

//append additional json to json file
$tempArray[] = $additionalArray ;
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);

file_put_contents('results.json', $jsonData);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### append data to `.json` file with PHP

- also keep with valid json structure
- not append array.
- append json to QuesAns`.json` file.
- overwrite data in file

```
   $data = $_POST['data'];
   //$data= 
   
   array("Q"=>"QuestThird","A"=>"AnswerThird");
        
   $inp = file_get_contents('QuesAns.json');
   //$inp='[{"Q":"QuestFurst","A":"AnswerFirst"},{"Q":"Quest second","A":"AnswerSecond"}]';     
  
   /**Convert to array because array_push working with array**/
   $tempArray = json_decode($inp,true);
        
   array_push($tempArray, $data);
   print_r($tempArray);
   echo'<hr>';

   $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);

   file_put_contents('QuesAns.json', $jsonData);
   
   print($jsonData);
```

Output:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [Q] => QuestFurst [A] => AnswerFirst ) [1] => Array ( [Q] => Quest second [A] => AnswerSecond ) [2] => Array ( [Q] => QuestThird [A] => AnswerThird ) )

---

> [{"Q":"QuestFurst","A":"AnswerFirst"},{"Q":"Quest second","A":"AnswerSecond"},{"Q":"QuestThird","A":"AnswerThird"}]

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * @var temp 
 * Stores the value of info.json file
 */
$temp=file_get_contents('info.json');

/*
 * @var temp
 * Stores the decodeed value of json as an array
 */
$temp= json_decode($temp,TRUE);

//Push the information in temp array
$temp[]=$information;

// Show what new data going to be written
echo '<pre>';
print_r($temp);

//Write the content in info.json file
file_put_contents('info.json', json_encode($temp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this PHP code to add json to a json file.
The code will enclose the entire file in square brackets and separate the code with commas.

```
<?php

//This is the data you want to add
//I  am getting it from another file
$callbackResponse = file_get_contents('datasource.json');

//File to save or append the response to
$logFile = "results44.json";


//If the above file does not exist, add a '[' then 
//paste the json response then close with a ']'


if (!file_exists($logFile)) {
  $log = fopen($logFile, "a");
  fwrite($log, '['.$callbackResponse.']');
  fclose($log);                      
}


//If the above file exists but is empty, add a '[' then 
//paste the json response then close with a ']'

else if ( filesize( $logFile) == 0 )
{
     $log = fopen($logFile, "a");
  fwrite($log, '['.$callbackResponse.']');
  fclose($log);  
}


//If the above file exists and contains some json contents, remove the last ']' and 
//replace it with a ',' then paste the json response then close with a ']'

else {

$fh = fopen($logFile, 'r+') or die("can't open file");
$stat = fstat($fh);
ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-1);
fclose($fh); 

$log = fopen($logFile, "a");
  fwrite($log, ','.$callbackResponse. ']');
  fclose($log); 

}

    ?>
```

GoodLuck