# appending to json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file, employees.json, that I would like to append data to this object.
The file looks like this:

```
var txt = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"Jerry","lastName":"Negrell","time":"9:15 am","email":"jerry@bah.com","phone":"800-597-9405","image":"images/jerry.jpg" },' +
'{"firstName":"Ed","lastName":"Snide","time":"9:00 am","email":"edward@bah.com","phone":"800-597-9406","image":"images/ed.jpg" },' +
'{"firstName":"Pattabhi","lastName":"Nunn","time":"10:15 am","email":"pattabhi@bah.com","phone":"800-597-9407","image":"images/pattabhi.jpg" }'+
']}';
```

I would like to append:

- firstName:Mike
- lastName:Rut
- time:10:00 am
- email:rut@bah.com
- phone:800-888-8888
- image:images/mike.jpg

to employee.json.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you parse it into a JS object, add it, and then serialize it into JSON again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse(txt);  //parse the JSON
data.employees.push({        //add the employee
    firstName:"Mike",
    lastName:"Rut",
    time:"10:00 am",
    email:"rut@bah.com",
    phone:"800-888-8888",
    image:"images/mike.jpg"
});
txt = JSON.stringify(data);  //reserialize to JSON
```

Comment: i surround that in a js file with `function add(){ .. }` and called it in html with `<form onsubmit="add()"><button>ADD</button></form>` and didnt see the values added to the employees.json file

Comment: Yea, the code only overwrites the "txt" variable with the new JSON data. You'd have to save it to your file manually. If you are using node.js it would do this using fs.writeFile

Answer (score 5):

JSON stands for Javascript object notation so this could simply be a javascript object

```
var obj = {employees:[
    {
      firstname:"jerry"
      ... and so on ...
     }
]};
```

When you want to add an object you can simply do:

```
object.employees.push({
   firstname: "Mike",
   lastName: "rut"
    ... and so on ....
});
```