# how to append JSON object by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, append

I don't know how to append my new object into already exist .json file
I run this program only in local

```
function writeJson(){
    var tempObj =  '{"name" : "kkk", "age":"123", "location" : "123123"}';
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(tempObj);

    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

I will wait your answer

Comment: is it that you want to add stuff to `tempObj` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "append"? Do you want to assign the value of `data` to a (new?) property of `jsonObj`? Or do you want to merge the value of `data` into `jsonObj` (assuming it is an object)? What do you want the result to be? Why don't your provide an example?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290572/appending-to-json-file-in-javascript

Comment: i want to insert  jsonObj into .json file

Comment: What does the original JSON file look like, and what should it look like after?

Comment: *"i want to insert jsonObj into .json file"* Do you mean to update the *file* on the server? You cannot do that with only client side JavaScript. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for guidance on how to properly ask a question.

Comment: That's still not clear. Do you mean that you want to add the `jsonObj` to the *data returned from the AJAX call*, or that you want to *amend the file as it's stored on the server*? They are very different tasks.

Comment: If you stick to JavaScript then nodejs is helpful in writing files.

Comment: [
  {
    "name": "이름",
    "age": "나이",
    "location": "지역"
  },
  {
    "name": "111",
    "age": "28",
    "location": "영등포"
  }

Comment: this is my .json file

Comment: and i want to add one object by using above code

Comment: As I said, you cannot use client side JavaScript to change the file on the server. Your webserver needs to provide an endpoint that accepts data and updates the file. How to do that depends on the webserver and the server side language you are using.

Comment: i didn't use concept of server and client.  all file are in local

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Browsers cannot write to the local file system. The only thing you could do is trigger the download of a (generated) file and let the user choose where to store it. See [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2897619/218196)

Comment: then is there no way to change the file by using user inputting data

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the format of your JSON object so that something like this will work for you:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"John":{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"},"Jeff":{"name":"Jeff","age":32,"city":"New Jersey"}}');
// append
data["Billy"] = JSON.parse('{"name":"Billy","age":64,"city":"Liverpool"}');
```