# JavaScript https get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, get

a get request to the address https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?format=json is sent too long with this code:

```
https.get("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?format=json", (res) => 
    {
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        let bodyCount = "";
        res.on("data", (dataCount) => {
        bodyCount += dataCount;
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
        bodyCount = JSON.parse(bodyCount);
        console.log(bodyCount);
        });
});
```

The process takes up to several seconds, so how to make it happen faster?

Comment: It's the server that is making the request slower, by taking more time to respond-send the data. Naturally you cannot do anything about this.

Comment: Is it possible to make this data stored in a json file, and update this file once a day?

Comment: Of course, why wouldn't it be? The downside would be that you would have to parse it again and rewrite it. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290572/appending-to-json-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering how I solved the problem:

```
setInterval(() =>{
    https.get("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?format=json", (res) => {
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        let body ="";
        res.on("data", (dataCount) => {
            body += dataCount;
        });
        res.on("end", () =>{
           fs.writeFile('./steamdatabase.txt', body, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
        });
});
});
}, 86400000);
```

...

```
 fs.readFile('./steamdatabase.txt', (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                       console.error(err)
                       return
                    }

            let body = JSON.parse(data);
            for(let i = 0;i<body.applist.apps.length;i++){
                if(body.applist.apps[i].name == generateParameter(args)) appidGame = body.applist.apps[i].appid;
                }
            if(appidGame) appInfo(appidGame,mess);
            });
```