# PHP add data to json file

Tags: php, json, merge

I try to add data to a json file.

First try:

```
$filename = "$root/nachrichten/bla.json";

$neueartikel = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true); /*until here everything works, I can loop the file*/

$neueartikel[] = array('titel' => 'bla',
                    'bild' => 'bla',
                    'url' => 'bla',
                    'ID' => 'bla',
                    'bildserver' => 'bla'); 

file_put_contents('$root/nachrichten/bla.json', json_encode($neueartikel);
```

Second try:

```
$filename = "$root/nachrichten/bla.json";

$neueartikel = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);

$neu[] = array('titel' => 'bla',
                    'bild' => 'bla',
                    'url' => 'bla',
                    'ID' => 'bla',
                    'bildserver' => 'bla');

$result = array_merge($neueartikel, $neu);

file_put_contents('$root/nachrichten/bla.json', json_encode($result);
```

How can I do this right????

UPDATE:

I also tryed what PotatoIng sayd:

```
$filename = "$root/nachrichten/bla.json";

    $temparray = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);

    $neu = array('titel' => 'bla',
                        'bild' => 'bla',
                        'url' => 'bla',
                        'ID' => 'bla',
                        'bildserver' => 'bla');

    array_push($temparray, $neu);

    file_put_contents("$root/nachrichten/bla.json", json_encode($temparray);
```

Still nothing (ignore this text I need to add some or else I can't submit -.-)

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the file? More specifically, does the owner/user of the PHP script have permissions to write to the file?

Answer (score 2):

Basic PHP: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variables:

```
file_put_contents('$root/nachrichten/bla.json', json_encode($neueartikel);
                  ^^^---
```

Your code is trying to write your file out to a directory whose name is literally `$`, `r`, `o`, etc...

Use `"`-quoted strings instead.

Comment: I tryed it this way now: file_put_contents("$root/nachrichten/bla.json", json_encode($neueartikel); and also: file_put_contents($root . "/nachrichten/bla.json", json_encode($neueartikel); but it's still not working :/

Comment: well, where is `$root` being defined, and what's its value?

Comment: $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]); it's above the code and I can loop $neueartikel: $filename = "$root/nachrichten/bla.json"; $neueartikel = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true); So I guess thats not the problem

Comment: the file may be 777, but what about the directory it's in?

Comment: It's also 777 I think I have to contact my host?? Until now there were never problems oO

Comment: no, you just need to do basic debugging. e.g. start testing things with is_file(), is_writeable() etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$data[] = $_POST['data'];

$inp = file_get_contents('results.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
array_push($tempArray, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('results.json', $jsonData;
```

answered on [Append data to a .JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895335/append-data-to-a-json-file-with-php) by "Tim"