# How do I record JSON data to file using PHP?

Tags: php, json

This is the code I've figured out.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$json = '{"username":"'.$username.'",'.'"email":"'.$email.'"}';
$file = fopen('token_data.json','w+');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);
?>
```

But this is absolutely not the right way.

Comment: 1) Put the data in an array and use `json_encode()` to encode it to JSON 2) When you want to add stuff, take the file content, decode it and add your array to it, and then encode it before you save it again.

Comment: What makes you think so? How would you improve it? Hint: Have a look at  [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Since `$_POST` *is* an array you can go straight to JSON with it.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I'm not getting errors, by this way I can't add data to the file, I'm just overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a more efficient way to do this.

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21725885)

```
// read the file if present
$handle = @fopen($filename, 'r+');

// create the file if needed
if ($handle === null)
{
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
}

if ($handle)
{
    // seek to the end
    fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);

    // are we at the end of is the file empty
    if (ftell($handle) > 0)
    {
        // move back a byte
        fseek($handle, -1, SEEK_END);

        // add the trailing comma
        fwrite($handle, ',', 1);

        // add the new json string
        fwrite($handle, json_encode($event) . ']');
    }
    else
    {
        // write the first event inside an array
        fwrite($handle, json_encode(array($event)));
    }

        // close the handle on the file
        fclose($handle);
}
```

Without decoding the whole JSON file into the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If your `$_POST` array has all of the data you need you can encode it as JSON and write to a file:

```
<?php

    $json = json_encode($_POST);
    $file = fopen('token_data.json','w+');
    fwrite($file, $json);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

If you want to append to the file you will need to read the file into an array first, add the newer parts of the array *then* encode it again before writing back to the file just like my friend @Rizier123 describes.

Comment: Just as @Rizier123 and I described it. Did you want me to write the code for you?

Comment: Please write it, I don't quite understand reading the file into an array...

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have asked @skygate but that is just not how Stack Overflow works. We're here to help you solve issues, not write the code for you. I have given you the steps. Read the file with something like `fopen()`. Decode the JSON into an array with something like `json_decode()`. Add new data to the array, maybe `array_push()`. Give that a shot and come back when and if you need help with the code *you have written*.