# Saving data to a json file with handsontable

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, handsontable

I'm trying to save spreadsheet data to json file. I use the following code. When i run this code nothing happens, and developer web console says 'no element found'. I'm using handsontable 0.29 Please help me with the working code. Your help is much appreciated.

**js Code**

```
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(save, 'click', function() {
    // save all cell's data
    ajax('save.php', 'POST', {data: hot.getData()}, function (res) {
    });
});
```

**save.php**

```
<?php
    $myFile = "save.json";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    $stringData = $_POST["data"];
    fwrite($fh, json_decode($stringData));
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: possible duplication source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895335/append-data-to-a-json-file-with-php

Comment: Mr. Beginner! You link has nothing to do with my question. Anyways thanks for your answer. I figured the way.

Answer (score 0):

**js code**

```
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(save, 'click', function() {

    ajax('save.php', 'POST', 'value='+JSON.stringify({data : hot.getData()}), function (res){
    });
});
```

**save.php**

```
<?php

    $stringData = $_POST["value"];

    $myFile = "general.json";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh)
?>
```

This works perfectly. Hope it would help someone else.