# how to save text files as array format?

Tags: php

I want to save the text file as the following format using PHP,

I have a PHP array as like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => sample@gmail.com
            [status]=> success

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => samplewallace@gmail.com
            [status]=> success
        )
)
```

I need to save above array in the text file as the following format

```
[
     {
        "email": "sample@gmail.com",
        "status": "success",

      },
      {
        "email": "sample@gmail.com",
        "status": "success",
      },
    ]
```

Comment: ... You mean as JSON?

Comment: try `json_encode ($your_array);`

Comment: Have you tried [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Comment: with tabulations and line breaks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append data to a .JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895335/append-data-to-a-json-file-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go,

```
file_put_contents( 'filename.txt', json_encode( $array ) );
```

Comment: if you want the looks too, than use 
`file_put_contents( 'filename.txt', json_encode( $array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ) );`

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367616/is-this-edit-absolutely-trivial-should-it-be-rolled-back)