# Save json object as decoded PHP array in file

Tags: php, json, fwrite

I have a large json object (174MB) https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3dpubc2emwrnyq/attributes-nodp.json?dl=0

I want to save the json object as decoded associative PHP array in a file for later reference/inclusion.

```
<?php $json_data = file_get_contents('attributes-nodp.json'); //This will retrieve your json data as a string
$arr = json_decode($json_data, true); //This will decode your string data into a PHP array; the true parameter makes it an associative array

$file = fopen("/home/kalugi/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/test/raw_attributes.php", "w");
//This will open a new file raw_attributes.php for writing

//This will write and close the file
fwrite($file  , $arr->__toString());
     fclose($file );
?>
```

However this throws an error

```
[23-Dec-2019 12:59:46 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function __toString() on array in /home/kalugi/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/test/write-array-to-file.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/kalugi/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/test/write-array-to-file.php on line 8
```

I then tried `var_export` to create a string that could be saved to the file and that didn't produce a file with anything.

```
<?php
$json_data = file_get_contents('attributes-nodp.json'); //This will retrieve your json data as a string
$arr = var_export(json_decode($json_data, true)); //This will decode your string data into a PHP array; the true parameter makes it an associative array
$file = fopen("/home/kalugi/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/test/raw_attributes.php", "w");
//This will open a new file raw_attributes.php for writing
//This will write and close the file
fwrite($file, $arr->__toString());
fclose($file);
?>
```

Please advise.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895384/1483629

Comment: Would you be better off to import this data into a database?

Comment: What is the objective? Preserving previous and storing it with new one OR directly storing the new one?

Comment: @vivek_23 I don't really need the json object as it's the wrong format for what I need.  I want to convert the json object into a a PHP array because I want to do some PHP operations on this data as a PHP array.  I figure I could just have the PHP array handy in a file for direct access and inclusion in a script.  It's a very big array though (174MB).

Comment: @NigelRen maybe.  I don't know anything about that though, so unless you have a very simple solution in mind that doesn't assume too much database know-how.

Comment: @ptrcao Then do the processing after your `json_decode` step. Where are you stuck? To store an array into a file, you can store it in JSON format or in a serialized way.

Comment: @vivek_23 Perhaps I will then.  Though, for educational purposes, does anyone know why I got that error?  Is it a syntactical error, or a mis-application of any of the PHP functions above?

Comment: @ptrcao `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function __toString() on array` came because you are calling a method `__toString()` on an array variable and not on an object of some class which has a  `__toString()` method.

Comment: @vivek_23, as they are reading a JSON and decoding it - not sure why they would want to store it back to a file as JSON.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, I am unsure too. Maybe, he wants to avoid an API call to dropbox again.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you're trying to invoke a __toString method on something that is not an object that has a __toString method (its an assoc. array).

If you want to save the var_export output of your data, then you have to pass `true` as a second parameter(to return the data instead of echoing it):

```
file_put_contents(PATH_TO_FILE, var_export(json_decode($json_data,true),true));
```

If you want to save the actual data for future use then it IMO it would be best to either parse the file and save it to a database or just save the JSON file and use that.

Comment: Please add proper error handling and/or use `file_put_contents()` instead

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski Changed it to use file_put_contents, not sure that this change is a good one since the initial answer's code was exactly mirroring OP's(just without the error), but whatever.

Comment: The reason I didn't originally use `file_put_contents()` as compared to `fopen` was because I was dissuaded by a point about performance - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768894/how-to-write-into-a-file-in-php#comment67259150_1768944) by John.  What do you guys make of it?

Comment: You can stick to old fopen() if you want but it then needs error handling.