# How to format JSON properly when using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I'm using PHP to take the inputs of an HTML form and add them to a JSON file like so:

```
$file = ('inputs');
      $array = array(
        'First Name' => $firstname,
        'Last Name' => $lastname,
        'Email' => $email,
   );
```

It worked initially but when I added multiple sets of data I was getting an "expected end of document" error in VS Code because I had to put [] tags around the data sets which are enclosed in {} tags.

```
// Example of JSON Data
[
       {
           "First Name": "James",
           "Last Name": "Smith",
           "Email": "jsmith@gmail.com",
       }
]
```

When I add more data it adds the {} data outside of the [] tags and I have no idea how to fix it so that it goes within the [] tags, so I'm hoping someone here has some tips to help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append data to a .JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895335/append-data-to-a-json-file-with-php)

Comment: You don't say how you generate JSON but there's only one [builtin tool](https://php.net/json_encode) and it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it in an array, just wrap an array around.

```
$array = ['First Name' => $firstname, 'Last Name' => $lastname, 'Email' => $email];
$array = [$array];
```

or just in one step

```
$array = [['First Name' => $firstname, 'Last Name' => $lastname, 'Email' => $email]];
```

To make it look nice, you can use the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option

```
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

```
[  
    {  
        "First Name": "James",  
        "Last Name": "Smith",  
        "Email": "jsmith@gmail.com"  
    }  
]
```

Comment: This sort of works but when I add more data from the form it puts all of them outside within new [ ] tags and causes errors in the JSON file

Comment: @JU5TU5 Please edit the question and show your code, otherwise we can't say what's wrong with it. Is it possible you're concatenating several calls to `json_encode()`? Two JSON strings put together don't make JSON, just like you don't get a two story building by piling up two houses.