# How do I get every array/variable from another php file without knowing variables/arrays names

Tags: php

I have a file named "example.php":

```
<?php

$var_0803202173634 = [[592,1004],[592,1004],[586,1179],[584,1288],[591,1374],[592,1429],[591,1452],[591,1461],[591,1362],[591,1263],[592,1163],[592,962],[598,962],[604,961],[611,960],[627,958],[632,957],[643,953],[646,951],[649,947],[653,939],[663,924],[669,909],[670,895],[668,886],[665,879],[659,867],[654,862],[647,855],[639,850],[632,848],[622,845],[607,844],[580,846],[560,849],[542,853],[527,857],[513,861],[489,870],[471,879],[447,892],[425,905],[406,918],[388,931],[373,944],[354,963],[344,975],[335,988],[330,1001],[325,1018],[325,1034],[328,1049],[333,1062],[342,1080],[353,1092],[366,1105],[387,1118],[415,1131],[442,1139],[505,1147],[547,1150],[589,1152],[622,1151],[660,1147],[725,1138],[746,1132],[801,1108],[832,1093]];

$var_0803202173637 = [[863,1076],[893,1057],[913,1041],[930,1026],[942,1011],[956,990],[960,979],[963,969],[965,957],[965,949],[963,942],[958,933],[954,925],[949,922],[940,917],[927,910],[915,906],[904,902],[892,898],[874,893],[860,889],[846,886],[831,885],[814,883],[798,881],[781,880],[757,880],[720,881],[697,883],[677,886],[658,887],[639,889],[620,893],[591,897],[582,898],[562,904],[551,908],[540,912],[529,915],[503,921],[485,926],[469,931],[465,934],[466,934],[469,933],[474,930],[479,927],[481,926],[485,925],[489,924],[496,923],[501,924],[506,924],[518,928],[528,931],[537,933],[543,936],[552,940],[567,946],[578,949],[584,953],[586,954],[585,955],[576,960],[553,966],[505,975],[411,985],[279,995],[22,1008],[177,895],[240,891],[347,881],[444,871],[528,862],[595,856],[667,842],[720,831],[752,823],[779,816],[793,812],[808,809],[821,808],[832,808],[843,808],[851,808],[853,808],[858,808],[862,810],[871,813],[883,818],[902,725],[907,728]];

$var_0803202173640 = [[911,730],[913,730],[913,631],[914,632],[914,633],[916,634],[917,636],[919,538],[919,540],[920,541],[920,542],[920,544],[919,546],[919,549],[918,553],[917,556],[916,558],[915,560],[915,562],[915,563],[914,564],[914,567],[912,570],[912,571],[909,575],[906,578],[903,581],[900,484],[898,487],[896,488],[894,491],[885,497],[880,500],[876,503],[871,506],[863,509],[846,516],[834,521],[822,526],[810,531],[793,537],[776,543],[748,555],[737,560],[704,576],[683,589],[663,602],[646,615],[624,635],[618,642],[606,662],[604,668],[602,684],[604,693],[607,698],[612,701],[618,703],[620,703],[623,704],[625,704],[626,704],[628,804],[628,803],[629,803],[630,802],[632,900],[634,897],[635,894],[638,889],[641,882],[644,874],[647,966],[649,953],[652,947],[654,941],[657,937],[660,1033],[661,1033],[662,1031],[665,1030],[668,1029],[669,1129],[670,1129],[670,1130],[670,1131],[670,1132],[670,1133],[672,1236],[676,1242],[681,1248],[685,1252],[688,1256],[694,1260],[704,1266],[723,1273],[742,1277],[767,1281],[792,1286],[816,1290],[843,1291],[865,1292],[879,1293],[918,1299],[936,1300],[952,1300],[968,1300],[985,1300],[1000,1300],[1012,1202],[1023,1202],[1037,1202],[1045,1202],[1051,1201],[1053,1201],[1057,1101],[1058,1101],[1060,1099],[1061,999],[1062,999],[1063,999],[1064,699],[1065,599],[1066,599],[1066,598],[1066,596],[1066,595],[1065,594],[1062,592],[1059,590],[1057,587],[1053,584],[1050,581],[1047,578],[1043,575],[1041,572],[1036,570],[1034,568],[1031,567],[1028,566],[1025,563],[1023,561],[1020,560],[1010,657],[1000,653],[988,649],[976,645],[962,641]];
```

I want to get every variable/array from "main.php" without knowing every variable/array name. Is it possible?

`get_defined_vars` gives me every variable from the whole system so it's not what I need.

Comment: What you really need to do? I can't imagine situation when I'd need to know in 1 file all vars from another one.

Comment: Looks like an XY Problem to me.  Time for a rethink.  Maybe `example.php` should be `objects.json` and the entire text structure should overhauled.  Could you `preg_grep()` the keys in `get_defined_vars()`? Yes, but ughk, I wouldn't.

Comment: Your file should probably contain _one_ array to begin with, under a name you know, instead of what you currently have.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. The situation is like that:
Im creating a plugin that creates dynamically php files with different mouse coordenates. Those coordenates are saved in a new file named by the date and page id. And the varibles are depending on the second of that day. I could do a loop to go through every possible name but, if i do it, the app could get stack if i have many different files

Comment: _“And the varibles are depending on the second of that day.”_ - make that _array keys_ instead of variable names then, and you problem is solved.

Comment: Honestly, Alvaro, I hope you do not use the accepted answer.  You are making an unprofessional mess of whatever you are building.  There are multiple clean ways to do what you need to do.  Such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895384/2943403

Comment: Hello @mickmackusa, you are right. I changed the whole system. Im saving the whole data from a particular day and particular page ID in a .txt as a string. After i explode it to get the array i wanted. Anyway, i didnt take the accepted answer as a solution. But is an interesting way to think for solving issues. Thanks a lot for being worry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the comments correctly suggesting to think about whether this is a preferrable approach at all (see [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)), I still think this might be a niche use-case that warrants a solution (after all, we simply don't know all the legitimate use-cases that may exist).

So here's what you can do: Use [`get_defined_vars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) after and before requiring the file. Then just include all the variables that didn't exist before the require (`array_diff` will not work in this case, as it will throw an "array to string conversion" error).

```php
<?php
$vars_before = get_defined_vars();

require 'example.php';

$vars_after = array_filter( get_defined_vars(), function( $key ) use ( $vars_before ) {
    return ! array_key_exists( $key, $vars_before ) && $key !== 'vars_before';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );

var_dump( $vars_after );
```

Comment: This platform is already a toilet.  Why doesn't  `array_diff_key()` work?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, `$vars_after = array_diff_key( get_defined_vars(), $vars_before );` would work, you'd just have to `unset( $vars_after['vars_before'] );` as well. I didn't run a performance comparison though. :)

Comment: nice one-liner!