# How to save click path as JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Let's say I have a quiz written in JavaScript. There are four different possible answers to each question. The participant clicks his way through the quiz one by one, he can cancel it at any time.

Now I want to save the user's click path including the respective timestamps. My idea is to record the click path as a JavaScript object and to transfer this object to the server via AJAX and save it in a JSON file after each click. Does that make sense?

The tricky things seem to me to be (1) to update the correct object (the correct line(s) in the JSON file) within a quiz session (no session cookies) for each click from the second click and (2) to append a new object for a new quiz session, both, if possible, without reading and rewriting the entire JSON file every time.

Your opinions and ideas are appreciated.

Edit: I have control over the backend and I'm using PHP.

Comment: No need to update a file dynamically. Keep the data in an object and then use `JSON.stringify` to convert the object to JSON. Then send that to the server to be saved.

Comment: But as the participant could cancel the quiz at any time, I need to save the object after every single click.

Comment: i guess it doesn't require an explicit action from the user to 'cancel', then? basically they could exit the tab or hit the back button at any time to cancel?

Comment: Ajax. ajax is how you send data to the server.

Comment: @diopside Exactly.

Comment: @KevinB What about the update issue?

Comment: @ThreeYearOld that's still just ajax. How you store the data on the backend is irrelevant to how you get the data there.

Comment: @KevinB Could you provide an example?

Comment: No, i cannot. that's far too broad, that'd be an entire application.

Comment: @KevinB Irrelevant or not, it has to be done. ;)

Comment: Yes, however you've provided no information on the backend. Is it php? coldfusion? .net? node.js? a SaaS? do you even have a backend? you can't just "write" to json.

Comment: @KevinB You're right. It's PHP.

Comment: The JSON file, if you're actually using a JSON file, has to be read entirely before you can modify it. and when you modify it, you write the whole thing. There is no only read and change the one line that changed.

Comment: @KevinB Are you sure about that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21725885/14512582

Comment: I mean, wow that's awful. the rule of thumb for json is never write json manually.

Comment: Alright. Thank you!

Comment: @KevinB Hah. `[{"You'd": ["hate", "the", "way"], "I": {"work": "then", "since": {"I": "write", "JSON": ["by", "hand"]}}}, "all", "the", "time"]`. Though, admittedly, if I'm computationally updating a `JSON` I'll always `JSON.parse()` or `json_decode()` first. I'm not going to edit it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to save the user's click path including the respective timestamps. My idea is to record the click path as a JavaScript object and to transfer this object to the server via AJAX and save it in a JSON file after each click.

Rather than sending the object to the server via Ajax and saving it in a `.json` file, you can, more simply, store a `JSON` (including timestamps) in `localStorage` and update it there.

See the `localStorage API`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

`localStorage` is both:

- more robust / persistent than keeping the data in an object
- less elaborate than Ajax-ing data to the server repeatedly

Comment: And how do you get the data on the server?

Comment: But as the participant could cancel the quiz at any time, I need to transfer the data after every single click.

Comment: @ThreeYearOld then do that. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I guess it doesn't work if the participant just closes the browser, does it?

Comment: @Rounin "Especially on mobile, the `beforeunload` event is not reliably fired." :(

Comment: No `sessionStorage`. I assume that if the user closes the browser the data won't transfer to the server.

Comment: Alright. I have to think about it. Thank you!

Comment: @Rounin Would you recommend one object per click? And then an array of objects or an object of objects overall?

Comment: @Rounin And if it is more complex? Apart from that, would you save one JSON file per "session"?

Comment: Although I suspect that answering my questions briefly would have taken less time than verbally refusing this, I thank you very much for your help and wish you all the best.